# Criando um painel de rede em PHP

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou com a seguinte dúvida tenho um banco de dados oracle com todos 
os nomes e ip dos usuários. Gostaria de usar esse banco nesse código ao invés de usar esse array teria como?

```
<!-- painel.php -->
<html>
<head>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="60">
</head>
<body>
  <h3>Painel de Monitoramento de Hosts</h3>
  <table border=1 cellspacing=3>
    <tr>
      <? 
        $servidores= array ("fabio.vivaolinux.com.br"=>"200.215.128.83", "webmail.vivaolinux.com.br" => "200.215.128.241" ); 
        while (list($site,$ip) = each($servidores)) { 
            $comando = "/bin/ping -c 1 " . $ip; 
            $saida = shell_exec($comando); 
            echo "<td>".$site."<br>".$ip."<br>"."Status:"; 
            if ( ereg("bytes from",$saida) ) { 
                echo "<b>online</b></td>"; 
            } else { 
                echo "<font color=red><b>não responde</b></font></td>"; 
            } 
        } 
     ?>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
<!-- fim do programa -->
```

Comment: Sim é possível substituir esse array por um banco de dados. Informe qual banco você tem e veja se o driver dele está disponível no php.

Comment: Como esta a estrutura do seu Banco de dados? Qual o banco de dados que esta utilizando?

Comment: No caso você irá precisar primeiro fazer uma conexão com o banco de dados, depois selecionar os dados nas tabelas desejadas e fazer o loop para exibir os dados.

Comment: eu estou usando o Sql oracle

Comment: Se puder colocar a estrutura da tabela é bom.

Comment: @rray imagino que a estrutura da tabela seja parecida com o `array` `create table servidores id int(11), site varchar(255), ip varchar(15))`, claro, estou supondo o mais basico possivel e nem sei se esta certo tbm.